# Tengo un problema al "traducir" a kotlin una funcion que fue hecha en java

Tags: java, kotlin

Soy un recién graduado de la universidad y estoy aprendiendo un nuevo lenguaje por mi cuenta en este caso kotlin. En la universidad utilizamos java y android studio. En resumen: el problema que tengo ahora es que queria copiar una bd ya hecha en sqlite a mi proyecto y encontré una forma que esta escrita en java y como estoy manejando un nuevo lenguaje estoy un poco perdido en como "traducir" esta linea de codigo a kotlin:

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
```

el fragmento completo de completo de codigo en java es:

```
private void copiarBaseDatos() {
        String ruta = "/data/data/com.example.sqlite/databases/";
        String archivo = "contactos.db";
        File archivoDB = new File(ruta + archivo);
        if (!archivoDB.exists()) {
        try {
            InputStream IS = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(archivo);
            OutputStream OS = new FileOutputStream(archivoDB);
            ***byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];***
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = IS.read(buffer))>0){
                OS.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            OS.flush();
            OS.close();
            IS.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Archivo no encontrado, " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error al copiar la Base de Datos, " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Llegué hasta aquí y me perdí

```
fun copiarBaseDatos() {
    val ruta: String = "/data/data/com.example.sqlite/databases/";
    val archivo: String = "contactos.db";
    val archivoDB: File = File(ruta + archivo);
    if (!archivoDB.exists()) {
        try {
            val IS: InputStream = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(archivo);
            val OS: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(archivoDB)
            //   var buffer : byte[] = byte[1024];
            //Aqui me trabe
            ***var buffer: Byte = Byte[1024];***


            int length = 0;
            while ((length = IS.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                OS.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            OS.flush();
            OS.close();
            IS.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Archivo no encontrado, " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error al copiar la Base de Datos, " + e.toString());
        }
    }


}
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar me hace un gran favor

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Así se crea un array de tipo `byte` en Kotlin: `val buffer: ByteArray = ByteArray(1024)`. Igualmente existen `IntArray`, `BooleanArray`, `FloatArray`, etc. También pueden ser creados así: `Array<Byte>(x) { ... }` donde `x` es el tamaño del array y `{...}` es el lambda para su inicialización.

Answer (score 0):

La linea que comentas:

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
```

esta serìa su versiòn en Kotlin, un `ByteArray` con longitud 1024:

```
val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
```

Por lo tanto esta serìa la versiòn Kotlin de tu mètodo:

```
private fun copiarBaseDatos() {
    val ruta = "/data/data/com.example.sqlite/databases/"
    val archivo = "contactos.db"
    val archivoDB = File(ruta + archivo)
    if (!archivoDB.exists()) {
        try {
            val IS =  getApplicationContext().assets.open(archivo)
            val OS: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(archivoDB)
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var length = 0
            while (IS.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0) {
                OS.write(buffer, 0, length)
            }
            OS.flush()
            OS.close()
            IS.close()
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Archivo no encontrado, $e")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error al copiar la Base de Datos, $e")
        }
    }
}
```